# Intel hd graphics 4600 drivers, Lenovo y510p

Tags: windows-10, drivers, intel-graphics

I'm trying to upgrade an old Lenovo y510p. 
While drivers for NVIDIA GeForce755M installed without any issues (I have a version dated 4/9/2019 now), Intel HD Graphics 4600 is quite old (8/24/2015). By visiting Levono, I found out that it's the latest one they officially provide. On Intel support, on the other hand, I can see, that they released updated versions plenty of times since the version Lenovo offers. 
I tried to upgrade the driver in several ways, including using `Intel Driver & Support Assistant` (which btw detects the current driver as an obsolete and offers an upgrade), however, whatever I do, I'm getting

`The driver being installed is not validated for this computer. Please obtain the appropriate driver from the computer manufacturer.`

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: I'm not sure how that may help. I can get the drivers manually, the problem is that *I can't install them*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Maybe you can't, but SDI can. It's not just a tool to search for up-to-date drivers, it can also install them for you. It's worth a shot, IMO, but it's up to you.

Comment: Intel doesn’t provide DCH drivers for your processor.  You will have to use the drivers provided by Lenovo.  You shouldn’t even be installing the Intel drivers since you have a Nvidia GPU.

Comment: @Ramhound I originally started upgrading drivers because I couldn't connect my laptop to a Samsung TV via HDMI. drivers seemed a possible issue.

Comment: @Didier this Snappy Driver Installer behaves like malware - everything it's done so far is just installed lots of things. it will be annoying to reinstall the OS because of this sdi. have you been using it?

Comment: I cannot make any recommendation with regards to Snappy Driver except to uninstall it.  I believe any applications that offers device drivers has being unnecessary.  This isn’t the first time that particular application has been suggested by that particular user.

Comment: I don't know where you got that from, @Ramhound... I've been using SDI for years, and it's never triggered any response from any AV software I was running at the time, nor has it "installed lots of things" on my PC. Vlad, are you sure you downloaded the proper software, from the editor's website and nowhere else? It comes in a .zip package, and once unzipped, lets you choose between x86 and x64, depending on your OS. It's usually branded by the version of Windows you've got installed (e.g. "1909 x86"), and runs without install, as a standalone program. I think you got the wrong package.

Comment: Did you choose the Lite version, with only the indexes, or the whole driver collection? Choose the former, the rest is useless, unless you want to create your own driver repository and serve other people online. Here: https://sdi-tool.org/download/ (click on the blue download button on the right).